# Review form stopped working (submitting)

Tags: magento-1.9, review

I'm working on a Magento website wich is still in development. Work started somewhere in august previous year but for unforseen circumstances the work on this site has been on hold for several months. Last week we have started working on the site again and I have noticed that the review form, wich we have incorp[orated on the product page, has stopped working. When a review is being submitted the error message 'Unable to post the review' is being displayed and the review isn't submitted.

As the review form worked flawless for some montyhs ago my first thoughts were that the automatic Magento updates are the cause for the corrupted review form. Can this indeed be the case? Has there been any significant changes to the review form in the last updates?

I have googled for a solution but haven't found any leads. Does anybody has an idea where to lok for the cause of the problem? BTW, I don't get any errors in the logs.

With kind regards,
Erik

Answer (score 0):

Has Magento been upgraded or security patched in the meantime? If so, one of the (overwritten) templates could be missing a form key (to protect against CSRF)

Comment: Unfortunally that isn't the problem. This morning I noticed that I am not able to add reviews to products in the backend.

Comment: Ah too bad because that would have been an easy fix :) I'm not sure then - also Magento doesn't have automatic updates, so it must be that someone changed something to the code or database.